# Magento Admin redirection issue

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, redirect, access

I am working on a multistore setup. There is a problem with admin area: it is redirecting after login to base domain admin domain.com

I am using this code in .htaccess for multiple stores:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)?domain\.us [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:usa]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)?domain\.us [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

Is there any way we can separate both admin panels? If an admin user logs in to domain.us so he can access only domain.us with all features, not the base domain.com ?

One more question: is there any difference of `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` website and Store?

Answer (score 2):

What you're reporting is the usual behaviour for Magento in a multistore setup.

Unfortunately I don't think there are any free extensions available that will do what you're wanting but this extension does allow to create permissions and access only for specific stores in admin: http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html

I would think that admin domain would still remain as your base domain though.

The difference between the `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` of `store` and `website` is that each would route the redirect to each specifically set store or website created in Magento system config when under that particular store or website scope..